# How can I get the names of all the plugins and active theme of any WordPress website?

Tags: android, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

How can I get the names of all the plugins and active theme from any WordPress site?

Example I will enter http://name-wordpress.com and get list of plugins and theme name.

Comment: You need to explain you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: SO is not a place where you ask us to write a solution to your problem when you've shown no effort to code anything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the active theme by right-clicking anywhere on the page > inspect element (this opens DevTools) > Network > open "style.css".

You can use the Network tab to see some plugins loading, but you can't see all of them.